# For Mysql ORDER BY LIMIT query when ordering by primary key do I need a composite index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

If I'm running a MySQL ORDER BY LIMIT query with the WHERE clause filtering on one column and the ORDER BY clause filtering *on the primary key column*:

a) Can I get away with a single index on just the column I'm doing the WHERE? example here would be index (team_id)

b) Or is it best to index on both the (WHERE column, ORDER BY column)? example here would be index (team_id, member_id)

I have a hunch that the database will be naturally ordered on the primary key column, and so I think I can go with a) and only a single index will be required. Can someone please confirm?

example database

```
CREATE TABLE `team_member` (
  `member_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  ...
  (several more columns of info)
  ...
   PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`),
   KEY `IDX_TeamMember_TeamId` (`team_id`)
) ...
```

example query

```
select *
from `member`
where `team_id` = 11111
order by `member_id`
limit 0,10
```

MySQL server version 5.6.10

Very large table, scale is big concern

Comment: Depends on the condition ```where `team_id` = 11111``` selectivity. If it filters less than ~5-7% of totasl rows amount then the index by `(team_id, member_id)` must increase the performance otherwise the composite index not needed.

Comment: InnoDB implicitly adds the PK to the end of your index.

Answer (score 1):

The Optimizer prefers to handle the `WHERE` clause completely before looking at the `ORDER BY`.

The `LIMIT` cannot be *efficiently* handled unless the entire `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` are handled by a single index.

The Optimizer will *sometimes* skip the `WHERE` clause and look for an index based on the `ORDER BY`.  This is your suggestion.  But it must scan through lots of rows with the 'wrong' `team_id`.  And it may have to scan the entire table before finding 10 rows.  So, this can be a 'bad' plan.

You *can* artificially change the `PRIMARY KEY` to optimize some important query. For your example:

```
PRIMARY KEY(team_id, member_id),
UNIQUE(member_id)
```

The `UNIQUE` preserves both the index and the uniqueness check you currently have.  The PK must be 'unique'; by having `member_id` in it, it is guaranteed to be unique.  The data is now ordered first by `team_id` (hence will handle the `WHERE` efficiently, and second by `member_id` so that the `ORDER BY` is handled.  And, because it got past both of those, your `SELECT` will touch no more than 10 rows (the `LIMIT`).

With that PK and that query, not only is it able to stop after 10 rows, but those 10 rows are likely to be in a single disk block.  (Or maybe a small number of 'consecutive' blocks.)  You can't get better than that.

Yes, InnoDB does order the data by the PK.

Why the goal of having only one index?  Multiple indexes in not a sin.  It is a very small burden on `INSERTs`, but potentially a big benefit to some `SELECTs`.

How big is the table?  What I recommend would be good even for a billion-row table.

The selectivity (cardinality) of the first column of a composite index is irrelevant.  The selectivity of the combination of columns may play a role.  However, your example is unlikely to be impacted.